# psftp batch script won't work

Tags: ftp, batch-file, windows-xp, sftp, putty

I'm trying to run a .bat file from windows xp using putty sftp. My code is below. For some reason, I keep getting an "access denied".

The annoying thing is that when I copy>paste these into the cmd prompt line by line, it works fine! I'm not sure if there's still some error with my code or if it's possible that the ftpsite.com won't accept incoming messages from a batch file?

```
    @echo off  
    psftp user@ftp.ftpsite.com -pw abc#!123  
    cd Data/out  
    get file.csv
```

Comment: psftp is not native windows command - it will be good to say where it is taken from...

Comment: the psftp command is used to run psftp.exe which is located in the same directory as the .bat file.

Comment: When you saved your commands to the file, what encoding was used?  Was it plain ASCII?  Or was it Unicode or UTF-8?

Answer (score 1):

Commands to PSFTP must be placed in a SCRIPT file as in:

Filename: myscript.scr

```
cd Data/out
get file.csv
exit
```

Then you call it with:

```
@echo off
psftp user@ftp.ftpsite.com -pw abc#!123 -b myscript.scr
```